Open3d: Basic operations on point clouds not working, exited with code=3221225477
I am learning Open3D 0.18.0 from the documentation, and I copied and pasted the code from the website. But the code is not working. The point clouds are visualized fine. But if I perform any operations on them, like transforms, paint, etc., I am getting the error [Done] exited with code=3221225477. Also, the function 'o3d.visualization.draw_geometries' is not working when I pass camera parameters to it.
Here is the code:
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys

def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
    #source_temp = copy.deep_copy(source)
    #target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
    target.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])
    #source.transform(transformation)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source, target])

def preprocess_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size):
    print(":: Downsample with a voxel size %.3f." % voxel_size)
    pcd_down = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size = voxel_size)
    radius_normal = voxel_size * 2
    radius_feature = voxel_size * 5
    print(":: Estimate normal with search radius %.3f." % radius_normal)
    pcd_down.estimate_normals(o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius = radius_normal, max_nn = 30))
    print(":: Compute FPFH feature with search radius %.3f." % radius_feature)
    pcd_fpfh = o3d.pipelines.registration.compute_fpfh_feature(pcd_down, 
                                                               o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius = radius_feature, max_nn = 100))
    return pcd_down, pcd_fpfh

def prepare_dataset(voxel_size):
    print(":: Load two point clouds and disturb initial pose.")
    demo_icp_pcds = o3d.data.DemoICPPointClouds()
    source = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(demo_icp_pcds.paths[0])
    target = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(demo_icp_pcds.paths[1])
    transformation = np.asarray([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                                [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
    source.transform(transformation)
    draw_registration_result(source, target, np.identity(4))
    source_down, source_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(source, voxel_size)
    target_down, target_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(target, voxel_size)
    return source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh

voxel_size = 0.05
source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh = prepare_dataset(voxel_size)

As soon as I comment all the following lines:
source.transform(transformation)
source.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
target.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])

The code works and the point clouds are visualized. But the code shows the same error if I uncomment any one of the lines.
In VS code I am getting the following error:
[Running] python -u "d:\python\Open3D\Practice.py"
:: Load two point clouds and disturb initial pose.

[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 2.787 seconds

Here is the system, open3d and python information:
`- Operating system: Windows 10 64-bit

Python version: Python 3.11.9 / output from import sys; print(sys.version)
Open3D version: output from python: print(open3d.__version__)
System architecture:  x64-based processor
Is this a remote workstation?: no
Open3D installation method?: pip`

I tried to run the code in virtual environment but still it didn't worked. The same lines when I commented them then the code started to work. Also I tried different installation commands but still the problem was same. Here are the commands:
pip install open3d
pip3 install open3d
pip install --user open3d


For what it's worth, 3221225477 is 0xC0000005, which is the Windows error code for "access violation".  It means a bad address was used.  You may need to go to the authors for support.

Issue solved! The problem was with numpy version which was 2.0. I recently installed python and directly used the command pip install open3d which installed numpy version 2.0 by default. numpy version 1.24.0 worked for me

I also meet this problem, and try built from source, but doesn't work, change the numpy version from 2.0.4 to 1.24.0 , it works, thanks
